# SQL Server 2008 R2 - sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sp-send-dbmail

At the beginning I mark - I'm not a specialist in writing code. I need your help. I want to implement an email notification system via sp_send_dbmail.

Code:

```
USE msdb
go

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='PROFILENAME',
    @recipients='myemail@email.com',
    @query_result_header=0,
    @attach_query_result_as_file=0,
    @query="select Kod,Nazwa from DATABASE.dbo.Towar where Kod NOT LIKE '%?%' and (AsId=205 or AsId=304 or AsId=289 or AsId=321 or AsId=306 or AsId=217 or AsId=261) and Aktywny=1 ORDER BY Kod",
    @body_format="text",
    @subject='SUBCJECT'
GO
```

The SQL query works and sends an e-mail, but also sends empty lines. for example. How to get rid of them?

```
1916                 SER TWAROGOWY WIEJSKI LUZ
```

I would also like sp_send_dbmail to send an email only when the query returns data. If there is no data - does not send messages.

Comment: What do you mean "empty lines"?  Your example doesn't show empty lines.  If you want the sending to be conditional, then you need an `if` before the call.

Comment: On a side note, I suggest you use `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` and enclose literals in ANSI/ISO standard single quotes, doubling single quotes within strings.

Comment: This is the e-mail. There are empty lines between the data. I prefer the message to look more legible. Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MZvgEiF_t4H-7vbHGrYAczPEfiayTAiG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `IF`, if you want a conditional email:

```
IF EXISTS (select Kod, Nazwa from DATABASE.dbo.Towar where Kod NOT LIKE '%?%' and AsId IN (205, 304, 289, 321, 306, 217, 261) and Aktywny = 1)
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='PROFILENAME',
        @recipients='myemail@email.com',
        @query_result_header=0,
        @attach_query_result_as_file=0,
        @query='select Kod, Nazwa from DATABASE.dbo.Towar where Kod NOT LIKE ''%?%'' and AsId IN (205, 304, 289, 321, 306, 217, 261) and Aktywny=1 ORDER BY Kod',
        @body_format='text',
        @subject='SUBCJECT';
END;

GO
```

Comment: This "empty lines" are carriage returns. `CHR(10)` and `CHR(13)`